# Pointer arithmetic resulting in incorrect address write

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here I am attempting to write the address of next `block_t` at the address where the previous block has its payload structure. This is just a PoC that I'm testing to integrate into my main code later on. However, instead of writing the address to the next block, it writes address to itself as you will notice when you see the output.

EDIT 1: So I guess the question now boils down to "How can I reuse the pointer allocated for the payload to point to another block?"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned word_t;

typedef struct block {
    word_t header;
    char payload[0];
} block_t;

static void set_next_free_block(block_t *block, block_t *nblock) {
    
    // Store the address of next block at the location where payload starts
    word_t *next_address = (word_t *)(block->payload);
    
    // Now write the address of next block here
    *next_address = nblock;
    
    return;
}

static block_t *get_next_free_block(block_t *block) {
    
    block_t *next_address = (block_t *)((word_t *)block->payload);
    
    return next_address;
}

int main() {
    block_t *block = (block_t *)malloc(sizeof(block_t));
    block_t *nblock = (block_t *)malloc(sizeof(block_t));
    block_t *next = NULL;
    set_next_free_block(block, nblock);
    next = get_next_free_block(block);
    printf("Block 1\nBlock address: %16x\n", (word_t)block);
    printf("Payload address: %16x\n", (word_t)block->payload);
    printf("Next: %16x\n", (word_t)next);
    printf("Block 2\nBlock address: %16x\n", (word_t)nblock);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the address added which I set inside `set_next_free_block` to point to address of `nblock` points to the wrong address.

When I run this, I get:

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: Firstly `char payload[0];` is not allowed in ISO C so you are relying on compiler extension

Comment: Yes, I know that is not valid, this is actually a snippet from a much larger homework where we have to break certain rules to implement a custom version of malloc (Malloc Lab).

Comment: `*next_address = nblock;` just writes out of bounds of the allocation (causing undefined behaviour). Maybe you wanted `word_t *payload;` instead of `char payload[0];`

Comment: What would be the correct way to write the address then?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do (e.g. if this is meant to be a linked list memory allocator, you would have both the next block pointer, and a payload)

Comment: Right, so in a case when it is an allocated block of memory, it need not contain any pointers, otherwise, it has to be added to an explicit free list for which it will have those pointers. So I'm trying to store the pointers within the space without memory overhead. I'm not sure if its still ambiguous.

Comment: At the moment you are not allocating any space for the payload so you will have to change that part of the design. If you are having the payload inline with the block then you need to allocate the space with the block (e.g. `malloc(sizeof(block_t) + 100)` for a 100-byte payload)

Comment: Thanks! Understood. But even if I'm not allocating space for payload, I do have space for a single pointer that was being used to point to payload right?
In that case, what would be the correct assignment?

Comment: [where we have to break certain rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860073/pointer-arithmetic-resulting-in-incorrect-address-write#comment109413097_61860073) ---> Code does not _need_ to do that, even if pre-C99.  Since C99 use member `char payload[];` as a _flexible array member_.

Comment: You don't have space for a single pointer. `char payload[0];` is (probably, in usual compiler extensions) a zero-sized array with no space.  `word_t *payload;` would be a single pointer

Comment: "But even if I'm not allocating space for payload, I do have space for a single pointer that was being used to point to payload right?" --> No.  "what would be the correct assignment?" --> Too many mistakes in the approach for a simple correct alternative.

Comment: @NishitMengar What information is `header` for?

Comment: Tip: a good solution will not use any _casting_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica header is basically used to store size and allocation information

Answer (score 1):

so with the function `set_next_free_block` you are trying to store the address of `nblock` in `block->payload`, right?

so first of all i changed `char payload[0]` into `word_t` to store the addresses properly. `char payload[0]` doesn't really make much sense to me.

then i simply casted the `nblock` pointer into a `word_t` to get its address and stored it inside `block->payload`.

and inside the `get_next_free_block` function, you did not need to cast `block->payload` into a `word_t *` before casting it again into a `block_t *`

does this code give the results you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned word_t;

typedef struct block {
    word_t header;
    word_t payload;
} block_t;

static void set_next_free_block(block_t *block, block_t *nblock) {
    block->payload = (word_t)nblock;
    return;
}

static block_t *get_next_free_block(block_t *block) {
    return (block_t *)block->payload;
}

int main() {
    block_t *block = (block_t *)malloc(sizeof(block_t));
    block_t *nblock = (block_t *)malloc(sizeof(block_t));
    block_t *next = NULL;
    set_next_free_block(block, nblock);
    next = get_next_free_block(block);
    printf("Block 1\nBlock address:\t\t%16x\n", (word_t)block);
    printf("Payload address:\t%16x\n", (word_t)block->payload);
    printf("Next:\t\t\t%16x\n", (word_t)next);
    printf("Block 2\nBlock address:\t\t%16x\n", (word_t)nblock);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

i get the following:

```
Block 1
Block address:                   15a4a10
Payload address:                 15a4a48
Next:                            15a4a48
Block 2
Block address:                   15a4a48
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually understood that the way I was attempting to modify char payload[0] was extremely incorrect. While our homework used GCC extensions to allow an array of length 0 to be declared just to add the pointer to the block structure, **an array of length 0 should be the last element in a structure.**

I am not adding the answer here, as this would be a help in homework in non-ethical ways, I'll just tell what was already available to us:

**If we want to use this payload pointer in multiple ways, we should declare it inside a union instead.**